# Install package which has setup_requires from local source distributions

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils

Take the following trivial package which contains setup_requires:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='my_package', setup_requires=['cython'])
```

Assuming I have done the following to build it to a source distribution:

`$ python setup.py sdist`

And downloaded the source distribution for Cython

`$ pip install --download ./dist/ --no-use-wheel Cython`

So now I have:

```
$ ls dist/
my_package-0.0.0.tar.gz
Cython-0.21.1.tar.gz
```

What I'd like to be able to do is install the package on a network-isolated machine using some combination of `--find-links`, etc.

I'd imagine I could do something like

`pip install --no-index --find-links="file:///$(pwd)/dists" dist/my_package-0.0.0.tar.gz`

However I get an error that looks like this:

`No local packages or download links found for cython` (Full text here:  http://paste.pound-python.org/show/IxmzEEfQ5yZRU45i2FBM/ )

What I've tried unsuccessfully:

Setting the following

```
[easy_install]
allow_hosts = ''
find_links = file:///$(pwd)/emr-sdists
```

in:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/distutils.cfg
~/.pydistutils.cfg
./setup.cfg
```

I'm currently using the `--net none` setting of docker to help debug this if it makes it easier for you to get to a reproduction.

Answer (score 5):

The problem (besides that your `--find-links` is typoed as `dists` instead of `dist`) is that the first thing pip does to install a package is run `python setup.py egg_info`, without bothering to pass along any of the package-finding information.  Pip doesn't actually *want* setuptools to install any dependencies!  It wants setuptools to spit out the dependencies as `egg_info` so pip can read them and go fetch them itself.

But dependencies in `setup_requires` are *always* installed on *any* invocation of `setup.py`.  I'd go so far as to say that `setup_requires` is completely incompatible with pip.

The alternative is...  to just put your build code in the `build` step.  Pip won't try to build your package until all of its dependencies are installed anyway.