# Python project installation without internet connection

Tags: python, debian

I need to install a python project on a machine without internet connection. During the creation of the deb package I downloaded all python requirements with `pip download` and I putted them into the deb.

When installing the deb on the machine I get errors from python packages not being found and I discovered that packages creating problems are the ones specified into the field `setup_requires` of `setup.py` files of the included packages.

For example the `PyJWT` package has `setup_requires=['pytest-runner']` but `pytest-runner` is not downloaded by `pip download` and during the installation this gives error.

My question are:

1. is there a way of having pip downloading all dependencies (also those on `setup_requires` fields)?
2. Is this the correct workflow for creating a deb that has to be installed offline?

Comment: Have you tried creating a `requirements.txt` from `pip freeze` and user that  file with pip download: `pip download -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, this is exactly what I've done. In a local working virtualenv of my project `pip freeze` gives not pytest-runner within the dependencies

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a real package. You might try to download it manually `pip download pytest-runner` or from pypi.

Comment: This answer might be helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307082/install-package-which-has-setup-requires-from-local-source-distributions